# Read file type extension association list

Tags: python, windows-10, file-extension

I'm writing a Python program that automatically runs another program. I wish to open such program without ever having to prompt user for that program's executable path, or ask user to create custom PATH variables. The program I wish to execute doesn't create a PATH variable to its executable, but does create file type extension associations. This program in my case is SolidWorks.

Here is how the file type association list is accessed via Windows control panel:
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477

How could I read this list or a specific entry from the list from outside of the control panel using Python to extract the program's path for a particular file type? In my case, I wish to extract the path to the SolidWorks launcher executable from .SLDPRT file extension assosiation.

Comment: You can "run" a file with its associated application by using [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) without know what it is. You can also use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and pass it the filename. Otherwise the information you want is somewhere in the Windows registry which you can read using the [`winreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#module-winreg) module if you know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the file extension information in the Windows Registry:

```py
>>> import winreg
>>> file_ext = ".py"
>>> k = winreg.QueryValue(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, fr"SOFTWARE\Classes\{file_ext}")
>>> k
'Python.File'
>>> winreg.QueryValue(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, fr"SOFTWARE\Classes\{k}\shell\open\command")
'"C:\\WINDOWS\\py.exe" "%L" %*'
```